# How to set a boolean property in NServiceBus MessageHandler through EndPointConfig

Tags: properties, boolean, config, nservicebus, endpoint

I want to set a value to a public boolean property in my NServicebus message handler through EndPoint config.

One way which I know is by creating

1. An interface with that boolean property.
2. A concrete class inherited from the interface.
3. Initializing / Setting the value in that concrete class.
4. Injecting the concrete class through End-point config.

Is there any other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Configure.Instance.Configurer
  .ConfigureProperty<YourHandlerType>(h => h.BoolProperty,
      Bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["YourSetting"]));
```

In future versions, this will be even [easier](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/2040).

Edit:
You can try registering late with `IWantToRunBeforeConfigurationIsFinalized`, as suggested by David.

You can also register the component early. Since NServiceBus registers handlers as [`DependencyLifecycle.InstancePerUnitOfWork`](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/blob/master/src/NServiceBus.Core/Unicast/Config/ConfigUnicastBus.cs#L164), your code should be doing the same

```
Configure.Component<YourHandlerType>(DependencyLifecycle.InstancePerUnitOfWork)
  .ConfigureProperty(h => h.BoolProperty,
      Bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["YourSetting"]));
```

Comment: Looks promising, but when I tried placing that in my endpoint config, I got 

"Cannot configure properties for a type that hasn't been configured yet:" XXX(handler Name).

 Apparently the handler is still not loaded hence the property configuring failed.

Any suggestions...

Comment: Yes that is correct, I am using "IWantCustomInitialization" along with "IConfigureThisEndpoint" and "AsA_Server"

Comment: Try implementing IWantToRunBeforeConfigurationIsFinalized instead. Separate class from your EndpointConfig.

Comment: Solution provided by Chris worked for me. I will also try the solution provided by David soon and share the findings.

Thanks both of you :)